# change s3 file object owner using aws-sdk gem

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I know how to update the owner of an object using aws cli but I want to do it in ruby way using aws-sdk gem. In Aws cli, we do

```
  aws --profile new-owner s3 cp s3://<bucket-name>/<samplefile.txt> s3://<bucket-name>/<samplefile.txt>
```

In the above way we can update the owner of the file in the aws bucket. How to do the above using aws-sdk gem... Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer, I have to replace the metadata_directive..

```
  @destination_bucket.object(target).copy_from(@destination_bucket.object(target), metadata_directive: 'REPLACE')
```